# How to access the particular directory using SFTP in C code

Tags: c, sftp

I have never used SFTP. please help me in accessing the directory using SFTP in c language.

**EDIT:**

```
while ((dirp = readdir (directory)) != NULL) { 
  if ( strstr(dirp->d_name , ".txt" )) { 
    printf( "found a .txtfile: %s\n", dirp->d_name ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: @Vagish : while ((dirp = readdir (directory)) != NULL) 
  {

   if ( strstr(dirp->d_name , ".txt" ))
   {
    printf( "found a .txtfile: %s\n", dirp->d_name );
   }
  } we have did the above code for getting the txt file from the directory. but now requirement got changed we need to access the directory through sftp. which is am not aware. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access directory using SFTP, you can use ssh library function.

Here is some sample code,

```
 do {
        char mem[512];
        char longentry[512];
        LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTRIBUTES attrs;

        /* loop until we fail */ 
        rc = libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex(sftp_handle, mem, sizeof(mem),

                                     longentry, sizeof(longentry), &attrs);
        if(rc > 0) {

            if (longentry[0] != '\0') {
                printf("%s\n", longentry);
            } else {
                if(attrs.flags & LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTR_PERMISSIONS) {
                  printf("--fix----- ");
                }
                else {
                    printf("---------- ");
                }

                if(attrs.flags & LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTR_UIDGID) {
                    printf("%4ld %4ld ", attrs.uid, attrs.gid);
                }
                else {
                    printf("   -    - ");
                }

                if(attrs.flags & LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTR_SIZE) {
                    printf("%8" PRIu64 " ", attrs.filesize);
                }

                printf("%s\n", mem);
            }
        }
        else
            break;

    } while (1);
```

For other api information, you can go through SFTP API documentation and give a try.
http://www.libssh2.org//libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex.html

Comment: sure i will try this